# How to print footnote at the end of a chapter

Tags: footnotes, chapters

As the title says. Instead of printing it at the bottom of the current page, print it at the end of the current chapter.

Comment: The `endnotes` package is done for that.

Comment: Alternatives to @Bernard's suggestion are the `enotez` and `pagenotes` packages. (The latter is automatically loaded by the `memoir` class…)

Comment: Doesn't that print them at the end of the DOCUMENT?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use packages like `enotez`, `endnotes` or maybe `pagenotes` for stuff like this. Since no MWE was provided the following examples show how to get the result for sections but the usage is analoguous for chapters.

### `enotez`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enotez,lipsum}

\setenotez{
  reset ,
  list-heading = \subsection*{#1}
}

\begin{document}

\section{Foo}

\lipsum[1]\endnote{test a}
\lipsum[1]\endnote{test a}

\lipsum[1]\endnote{test a}

\printendnotes

\section{Bar}

\lipsum[1]\endnote{test b}

\lipsum[1]\endnote{test b}
\lipsum[1]\endnote{test b}

\printendnotes

\end{document}
```

### `endnotes`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{endnotes,lipsum}

\counterwithin{endnote}{section}
\renewcommand\theendnote{\arabic{endnote}}

\begin{document}

\section{Foo}

\lipsum[1]\endnote{test a}
\lipsum[1]\endnote{test a}

\lipsum[1]\endnote{test a}

\theendnotes

\section{Bar}

\lipsum[1]\endnote{test b}

\lipsum[1]\endnote{test b}
\lipsum[1]\endnote{test b}

\theendnotes

\end{document}
```

### `pagenote`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pagenote,lipsum}

\makepagenote
\renewcommand*{\notedivision}{\subsection*{\notesname}}
\renewcommand*{\pagenotesubhead}[2]{}


\begin{document}

\section{Foo}

\lipsum[1]\pagenote{test a}
\lipsum[1]\pagenote{test a}

\lipsum[1]\pagenote{test a}

\printnotes*

\section{Bar}

\lipsum[1]\pagenote{test b}

\lipsum[1]\pagenote{test b}
\lipsum[1]\pagenote{test b}

\printnotes*

\end{document}
```